# Why mtime of device files is not getting updated?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, linux-device-driver, stat

when I do a stat on input device files like /dev/input/event* I get mtime of the file as the system boot time.

It should at least get the key strokes and update the file's mtime as the current time!!

Does anybody knows the reason why mtime of these input device files is not getting updated?

Comment: Why should the `mtime` be updated? The device file node itself does not change at any point, it's just an interface that you can use to communicate with the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

> **`mtime`** (modified time) is updated when one performs a **`write()`** on the file.

The virtual dev files mentioned are **NOT** written-to from user-space. Updates from the underlying drivers to notify the user-space applications do **NOT** count as modifications to the file.

Comment: This is news for me that mtime of these files will not get updated. SO, is there a way that I can detect whether a user is using this desktop and it is busy. Basically I was doing stat on these device files to check if the machine is idle or not. I guess I can use some ACPI calls ( if exposed ) but that would heavily depend on the firmware.